# Why does my Echo Server not work on localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, echo

I am trying to create an echo server with Node.js so it should read body of incoming requests and send that same body as the response. You can see below my code. Basically when I run it and on another terminal, I type `curl --location --request POST 'localhost:3000' --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --data-raw 'Test message'` to test it, it prints the body inside the curl terminal and server terminal, but not on localhost.

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((request, response) => {

    
    let body = [];
    request.on('data', (chunk) => {
      body.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
      response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

      response.write(JSON.stringify(body));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
      response.end();
    });
}).listen(3000, 'localhost');
```

Comment: Buffer.concat concats buffers, not strings, you prob need `body.push(Buffer.from(chunk));` instead, though I'm not sure

Comment: Are you trying to open this from your browser? You need to send a Post response to see an output and that would be possible from a tool like Postman

Comment: `curl   http://localhost:3000  --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --data-raw 'Test message'`

Answer (score 1):

`curl` doesn't print the **request** body, it prints the **response** body the server is returning to you. In other words - this echo server works as planned.

Comment: Oh I see, but shouldn't this be printed on localhost too? Sorry I'm very new to web dev

Comment: @chrysa I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "printed on localhost", but if you bring the process running the server to the foreground, you'll see the same message in its standard output (created by the `console.log` call)